# How can I access Redux State in createContainer (react-meteor-data)?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, react-redux

**Stack**: Meteor 1.5, React, Redux, React Router 4

I am trying to display a selection of events in a React component. The events should be filtered based on some Redux state. The filtering should happen server side (to minimize traffic) - i.e. via parameters in the subscription.

Now I don't want all my Meteor date in the Redux state, but only some general application settings (user settings, filter, location and such).

**My approach is the following:**

1. Connect a dumb component with Redux state and get filter
2. Wrap connected component in createContainer and pass props (which should include filter).

**My Problem is:**

Props don't include filter. Anybody knows why? Code is below. The console log only displays props of the Home component (i.e. the unconnected component).

```
class Home extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                { /* display events here */ }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        filter: state.filter
    }
}

let connectedHomeComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,)(Home)

export default connectedHomeContainer = createContainer(_ => {
    console.log(_);
    let eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('getEventsByFilter');
    let loading = !eventsSub.ready();
    let events = null;
    loading ? (events = null) : (events = Events.find().fetch());
    let eventsExists = !loading && !!events;
    return {
        loading,
        events,
        eventsExists,
    }
}, connectedHomeComponent)
```

Comment: Did you make sure that `state.filter` is not `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Also as far as i can see from the docs the arrow function passed to `createContainer()` gets passed the props that get passed to your `connectedHomeContainer` when you render it and not the ones redux injects. Turn it around and wrap the `createContainer()` call with `connect()` and it should work.

Comment: @trixn: yupp, made sure that state.filter isn't null (also used other states to test)
Wonderful! Turning it around worked. Do you want to write an answer, or do you want me to self answer? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped your `Home` component in the wrong order. Your callback function gets passed the props that your `HomeContainer`component gets passed. So if you want redux to inject the `filter` prop into your `HomeContainer` then you have to turn it around:

```js
const HomeContainer = createContainer(_ => {
    console.log(_);
    const eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('getEventsByFilter');
    const loading = !eventsSub.ready();
    let events = null;
    loading ? (events = null) : (events = Events.find().fetch());
    const eventsExists = !loading && !!events;
    return {
        loading,
        events,
        eventsExists,
    } }, Home)

export default connectedHomeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeContainer)
```

Side Note: Use `const` as a default and only change it to `let` if you need to mutate the variable later on.

Comment: used let only because I thought for a moment that maybe because of const it couldn't add the props ... silly of me, I know :D cheers!